# Camera always returns resultCode as 0

Tags: android

I am trying to develop using camera in my android application.

The problem is that the camera always returns a result code of 0, irrespective of if I press done or cancel.
The code snippet I use is as follows:

```
protected void startCameraActivity()
{

    Log.i("MakeMachine", "startCameraActivity()" );

    File file = new File( _path );
    Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile( file );

    Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );
    startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
}
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
{   

    Log.i( "MakeMachine", "resultCode: " + resultCode );

    switch( resultCode )
    {
        case 0:
            Log.i( "MakeMachine", "User cancelled" );
            break;

        case -1:
            Log.i( "MakeMachine", "User done" );
            onPhotoTaken();
            break;
    }
}
```

The logcat shows:

```
05-31 14:58:15.367: E/asset(29114): MAS: getAppPckgAndVerCode package: makemachine.android.examples === version 1
05-31 14:58:15.398: D/dalvikvm(29114): Trying to load lib lib_glossary.so 0x0
05-31 14:58:15.414: D/dalvikvm(29114): Added shared lib lib_glossary.so 0x0
05-31 14:58:26.125: I/MakeMachine(29114): ButtonClickHandler.onClick()
05-31 14:58:26.125: I/MakeMachine(29114): startCameraActivity()
05-31 14:58:26.507: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29114): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-31 14:58:36.375: I/MakeMachine(29114): User cancelled
05-31 14:58:36.375: I/MakeMachine(29114): resultCode: 0
05-31 14:58:50.945: I/MakeMachine(29114): ButtonClickHandler.onClick()
05-31 14:58:50.945: I/MakeMachine(29114): startCameraActivity()
05-31 14:58:51.429: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(29114): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-31 14:59:01.554: I/MakeMachine(29114): User cancelled
05-31 14:59:01.554: I/MakeMachine(29114): resultCode: 0
```

Comment: Can you show us the logs.that would help to solve the issue.

Comment: I have included the logcat details...

Comment: If you are saving your image on sd card then have you added the write permission in manifest ?

Comment: @AkhilaNair Did you get any solution to this?

I tried all the ones suggested here. But nothing worked for me.

Answer (score 12):

The issue (in android >= 5.0) might be with `singleInstance` mode.

if you have your activity `launchMode` set to `singleInstance`, then in android < 5.0 you will receive cancelled result immediately. In android >=5.0 you will have `resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`.

Try using `launchMode = singleTask`. It is much like `singleInstance`, but allows other activities to be launched on the task.

More info here:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode

Comment: Issue is fixed after changing from singleInstance to singleTask but still have confusion, why this works? Any other info please

Answer (score 9):

As per the comments section, the reason that the `resultCode` was returning 0 (meaning the result was cancelled) is because when taking a picture to save to the SD card, you need to add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your manifest.

Answer (score 2):

Also, sometimes the issue causes due to not personally adding a required subfolder. The application crashes silently resulting result code as 0 every time.

Comment: This is exactly what happened to me. Definitely check the entire path exists before passing the photoURI.

Answer (score 2):

I was experiencing this same issue.  Camera works on 5.0+ with lauchmode=singleInstance returning a correct "RESULT_OK" but on Android 4.0 I was getting back a 0 until:

> Android 4.0 switched to "launchMode=singleTask" in the
>   AndroidManifest.xml for the Activity calling the camera resulting in
>   "RESULT_OK" == 1

This is useful for apps with backwards compatibility.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved my problem by doing the following changes...

```
private void takePictureFromCamera() {
    Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
    // Ensure that there's a camera activity to handle the intent
    if (takePictureIntent.resolveActivity(activity.getPackageManager()) != null) {
        // Create the File where the photo should go
        File photoFile = null;
        photoFile = createImageFile();
        // Continue only if the File was successfully created
        if (photoFile != null) {
            Uri photoURI = FileProvider.getUriForFile(activity,
                    "com.example.provider",
                    photoFile);
            takePictureIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI);

            //COMPATIBILITY
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                takePictureIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            } else {
                List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = activity.getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(takePictureIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
                for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
                    String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
                    activity.grantUriPermission(packageName, photoURI, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                }
            }
            //COMPATIBILITY
            startActivityForResult(takePictureIntent, CAMERA);
        }


    }
}
```

I found the solution in:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37835499/result-code-0-for-camera-intent)

Answer (score 0):

For android 9+ you have to add `android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"` this line to your manifest file in application tag,if not added.