# Result code 0 for Camera Intent

Tags: android, android-camera

Code:-

```
  Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);                                   
        try{
               imageUri = Uri.fromFile(File.createTempFile("image", ".jpg"));
           }catch (Exception ex){
               ex.printStackTrace();
          }

   intent.putExtra(android.provider.MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

I am using all permissions related to this in android manifest file...
that above intent is working fine in mot g3 turbo and many more devices but in the case of only nexus 5 the resultCode is coming 0.. why?

Comment: There is no requirement for `File.createTempFile()` to return a file path that is world-writeable. I would expect this code to fail on lots of devices.

Comment: [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/Content) uses files on external storage. However, that is going to start failing as a technique, as [Android N is beginning to ban `file:` `Uri` values](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/14/psa-file-scheme-ban-n-developer-preview.html). [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Camera/FileProvider) is the same as the first one, but uses `FileProvider`, to allow the third-party camera app to save the image directly to my app's internal storage.

Comment: "still I used the Uri for fulfill my requirement" -- you can never raise your `targetSdkVersion` above 23.

Comment: @CommonsWare...That's why i used this sir...actually my targetSDKVersion is 22... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With the guidance of CommonsWare Sir, I resolved my problem by doing the following changes...

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
destination = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/image.jpg";
outputUri= Uri.fromFile(new File(destination));
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputUri);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
  intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
} else {
  List<ResolveInfo> resInfoList = getPackageManager().queryIntentActivities(intent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY);
  for (ResolveInfo resolveInfo : resInfoList) {
      String packageName = resolveInfo.activityInfo.packageName;
      grantUriPermission(packageName, outputUri, Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION | Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
  }
}         

startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
```

Comment: @Hey Saurabh i am using your solution but still getting result code 0 in case of Nexus (6.0.1)but it's working in Moto  Power E3 (version 6.0)

Comment: got any solution for this, i am using nexus 6p , used this code, but still getting same problem

Comment: Most likely it is because Environment#getExternalStorageDirectory is deprecated and I'm fairly certain it doesn't play well with devices that do not have an external SD card (or something similar).